# Can I trap signals in R?

Tags: r, error-handling, sigint, sigterm

In bash I can trap `SIGINT`, `SIGKILL`, `SIGTERM`, and so on. That allows me to do different things depending how the program was unexpectedly stopped.

Is there a way to do this in R?

Comment: Check out `help(conditions)`

Comment: Thanks @RichardScriven ! Do you want to make that the answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @RichScriven, I know it's been a couple of years, but ... `tryCatch` only seems to catch errors and warnings, not external signals (such as HUP, TERM). I cannot seem to make an R script recognize when it has been HUPed and stop gracefully. I believe there's a distinction between "unexpectedly stop" (some error condition) and "stopped by external influence" (such as SIGHUP). What am I missing in the docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding a bit on my comment which OP asked me to post as an answer

---

The help file for *conditions* has the description

> These functions provide a mechanism for handling unusual conditions, including errors and warnings.

There are many handling functions explained in the file, with examples. So I suggest starting with

```
help(conditions)
## and
example(conditions)
```

Additionally, `tools::assertCondition` might be worth a look too. It is linked at the bottom of the *conditions* documentation.

Comment: This is not the correct answer. The correct answer is: `help(Signals)`