# How to get R to save its state when killed?

Tags: r

I would like to assign some code that will be run when R is killed, for instance, `save(list=ls(),file="dump.RData")`. I thought this would be by trapping signals, e.g. `SIGTERM`, as referred to in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27950443/can-i-trap-signals-in-r), but there's nothing about signals from the shell in `?conditions`.

`?conditions` does mention user interrupts; you can e.g. catch a `Ctrl-C` with `withCallingHandlers( Sys.sleep(10), interrupt=function (e){cat("I saw that.\n")} )`, but this doesn't catch SIGTERM.

How can I do this?

Comment: What I'm reading indicates that R is not notified when the process is killed with that signal.

Comment: @BondedDust Ah, right, I meant SIGTERM.  Edited.  But, if there's another signal it can trap, then that would do also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed if you send `SIGUSR1` to an R process, it will dump the workspace and stop. On Linux you can do that with

```
kill -USR1 Rpid
```

where `Rpid` is the process id of the R instance you want to stop. You can find it with `pgrep` for instance.

If R is running in a terminal, you can interrupt it with `CTRL-Z` and then type

```
kill -USR1 %
```

Comment: edited so that it answers the question; hopefully what I said is right.