# CTRL+C exits R in windows

Tags: r, rstudio

Is there a way to change behaviour of CTRL+C in R. Currently it is exiting R terminal, I prefer at least it asks if it should exit the terminal, or just clean the current line as it does when you run R through Rstudio

Edit 1: I am using R through command prompt in Windows. Not through RStudio.

Comment: isn't this just the default behaviour on most (if not all) terminals

Comment: CTRL-C usually maps to the SIGINT signal. Reading up on `help(conditions)` will supposedly tell you how to trap that signal, as said here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27950919/3688648

Comment: press `Esc` key for clearing the current line on RStudio console. `Ctrl+D` also works.

Comment: modify keyboard shortcuts: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/206382178?version=0.99.903&mode=desktop

Comment: @Sathish I am not using RStudio, I am calling R through command prompt directly

Comment: I think you need to change the .lnk file for setting windows shortcuts. `R.utils` package has function to get and set shortcuts such as `readWindowsShellLink`

Comment: on the current line, press `Home` to move the cursor to the beginning of the line. Then press `Ctrl+K`

Answer (score 1):

@Sathish answer seems to be working. Home then Ctrl + K. Thanks